# How to save HTML page with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

```
Actions action=  new Actions(getDriver());
            action
                    .keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
                    .sendKeys("s")
                    .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL)
                    .sendKeys(scenario.getName())
                    .keyDown(Keys.ALT)
                    .sendKeys("s")
                    .keyUp(Keys.ALT);
            action.build();
            action.perform();
```

It didnt open dialogue window for saving, so first step is not working.
scenario.getName() is for setting title
im trying to save page with selenium and it didnt work.
I mean press "Ctrl+S" then pass the title, then save.

Comment: It is possible to just get the source code: `driver.getPageSource()`

Comment: Why selenium? Why not Windows Application Driver?

Comment: @dosas getPageSource is only downloading clean html, without any colors, etc

Comment: @pburgr becouse i want to save page after failed test and im using for it selenium and cucumber

Comment: @Rollermix you can use WAD for saving the page only.

Comment: @pburgr i forgot, im testing app on Ubuntu :)